# ng-maxlength issues in angular 1.4.12

Tags: angularjs, ng-maxlength

Previously in angular 1.3.20 I could write a directive that accepted the ng-maxlength attribute, and apply it to an input inside its template. The HTML with the template inserted would look like this:

```
<my-directive ng-maxlength="5">
    <input type="text" maxlength="{{ngMaxlength}}">
</my-directive>
```

I've since updated to angular 1.4.12 and now my directive has the maxlength error flag set, when it is initially populated with the number 0 (I don't think this matters, just mentioning). As soon as I change the value by typing inside the input, ng-maxlength starts working as expected.

I've found through some trial and error that if I change the attribute name to say test-maxlength, all becomes well.

I have made two codepens to check out, one using 1.3.20 and one using 1.4.12. They both have two examples one with ng-maxlength and one with test-maxlength. If anyone has any ideas what is happening here that'd be great thanks!

[v1.3.20] http://codepen.io/jwt02180/pen/GqjpoG/

[v1.4.12] http://codepen.io/jwt02180/pen/eZPyNB/

Comment: Through some extra checking, I've found that setting the ng-model to a string instead of a number clears up the problem as well. Does anyone have any thoughts as to what's going on?

Comment: Also in playing with different versions, this behavior was introduced in version 1.4.6, which has a fix specifically mentioning ng-maxlength changes: [fix(ngModel) #12658](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/12658)